# How is the jQuery slider implemented?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Does anybody know how the jQuery slider is implemented? Does it use the JavaScript canvas library to draw the two guiding lines or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

jQuery slider uses HTML elements to build the slider. It doesn't use the canvas library.

This is how the slider is built:

```
<div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 17%; width: 50%;"/>
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 17%;"/>
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 67%;"/>
</div>
```

The classes: `ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-state-default` are all from the [jQuery user interface CSS framework](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API).

In short this plugin uses a mixture of HTML elements, CSS styling and jQuery events to mimic a slider control

Answer (score 2):

It's open source, you can see the source [here](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.1/ui/ui.slider.js).  It does not use canvas, just html elements.